# Why does a process sometimes hang after an input is presented?

Tags: python, input, freeze

Why does a process sometimes hang after an input is presented? About 80% of the time the code runs completely fine until the end, but sometimes immediately after an input is given the process halts and doesn't give an error, just behaves as if its in an infinite loop.

I've attached the code below, it's an attempt to replicate the game Hangman.

word_bank.csv is just a 1xn array of words for the game to randomly choose from.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import sys


class Hangman:
    
    def __init__(self, guesses = 10):
        
        self.word_bank = list(pd.read_csv('word_bank.csv')['Word'])
        self.incorrect_guesses = []
        self.correct_guesses = []
        self.guesses = guesses
        self.guesses_made = 0
        
        self.generate_word()
        self.gameplay()
        
    def generate_word(self):
        self.word = random.choice(self.word_bank)
        self.word_bank.remove(self.word)

        
    def display(self):
        
        print('incorrect letters ' + str(list(set(self.incorrect_guesses))))
        
        self.display_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(len(self.word)), '_')
        
        for i in set(self.correct_guesses):
            #Get the location of each letter within the word.
            self.lol = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(self.word) if char == i]
            for j in self.lol:
                self.display_dict[j] = i
        
        
        for k in range(len(self.display_dict)):
            print(self.display_dict[k], end=' ')
            

            
    def game_logic(self):
        
        #input cant be '', or more than one letter unless its the word itself.
        user_input = input('Your guess is ').lower()
        clear_output(wait=True)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        
        if user_input in self.word:
            self.correct_guesses.append(user_input)

        else:
            self.incorrect_guesses.append(user_input)
            self.incorrect_guesses.sort()
        
        
        
    def gameplay(self):
        
        while len(set(self.correct_guesses)) < len(set(self.word)) and self.guesses_made < self.guesses:
            
            
            self.game_logic()

            self.display()
            
            self.guesses_made += 1
```

Comment: Before posting, make sure that the code is properly formatted. It's present in both the preview window when writing, and in the review window before posting.

Comment: Have you run this code with a debugger? Also, provide a [mre], as currently, this code doesn't run at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but `clear_output(wait=True)` looks like a possible culprit.

Comment: The issue is coming from either pandas or clear_output because I ran it many times without those things and it worked perfectly.